# Probability that the sample size will be greater

Tags: statistics

A courier service company wishes to estimate the proportion of people in various states that will use it services. Suppose the true proportion is 0.06.

If 221 are sampled what is the probability that the sample proportion will be greater than 0.1?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexhange.com! You may want to visit https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question for information that will help you attract quality answers.

Comment: Are you familiar with the confidence interval ?